# How can I download a NextJS page as a static HTML file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

so I have this website made with Next and on a page there are some graphs (the graphs content changes as it fetches an API) and info.
I want to add a button to the page and when pressed it download the page as a HTML file and includes all the JS and CSS in the HTML file instead of separately, does anyone have any idea as to how to approach this problem. (The graphs content should be the same content as it was on the time of downloading)

(The reason why I want to do this is because I want to distribute these files to others and I want to allow them to read it w/o an internet connection)

Comment: This is a big question. You'd have to store the data to a local file and somehow get it to load when the site package is opened in a browser (rather than making the API call). I'd look for a different strategy, such as PDF generation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really download a React 'page' because there are no pages in React to download.

Next further complicates this because it server-side renders everything and rehydrates client-side. If you inspect one of your pages, you'll see the JSON blocks Next uses for data. Look for the `__NEXT_DATA__` script (usually in the footer of your page).

I think the two strategies you could use:

- Screen-capture of the graphs during your build sequence and push them over to an AWS S3 bucket or similar (cumbersome)
- When I ran into a requirement like this, I just made the data for the graph available as a JSON download just below the graph and it satisfied the use case sufficiently.

If you just want to download the assets and take a look, a workaround is probably leveraging the [`next/export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) package. This allows you to run `yarn build` and generate a static export of your entire site. This should include the file you're looking for.

Just some ideas to think through.